# ggplot2 - How to plot graphs side by side leaving only one legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, position

based on the sample dataset below, I Iam trying to make 2 graphs and place them side by side. I have tried using the `cowplot` package to do so. The final output was really messy.

Is there a way I could plot them side by side displaying only 1 legend, centralized on the bottom (since both graphs contain the same elements)?

```
df <- data.frame(Year = c(rep(2012,5), rep(2016,5),
                          rep(2012,5), rep(2016,5),
                          rep(2012,5), rep(2016,5)),
                 Category = rep(c('A1','A2','A3','A4','A5'),6),
                 Group = rep(c('T1','T1','T1','T1','T1',
                           'T2','T2','T2','T2','T2',
                           'T3','T3','T3','T3','T3'),2),
                 Variable = runif(30,0,100))


plot2012 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Group, y = Variable)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), stat = 'identity') +
  ylim(0,500) +
  labs(y = 'Variable') +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10))

plot2016 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Group, y = Variable)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), stat = 'identity') +
  ylim(0,500) +
  labs(y = 'Variable') +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

Any other general comments one the formatting/code are welcome

Comment: By the way, `plot2012` and `plot2016` are the same. It seems like you forget to subset `df` by `Year`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `facet_grid` to your `ggplot` call.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Group, y = Variable)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), stat = 'identity') +
  ylim(0,500) +
  labs(y = 'Variable') +
  # Generate plots as panel based on Year
  facet_grid(. ~ Year) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10))
```